# How to delete old devices from the Ubuntu One device list?

Tags: ubuntu-one

I have had several Virtual Box and other installations on old computers that I have used to access a common set of files but it seems I can only delete the currently connected device but not the obsolete ones that often no longer exist or have crashed and needed a reinstall. This generates a new device name each time, but the old ones can no longer be deleted. I'm sure I did have this option before but now only the "currently connected" device can be removed from the list which seems silly if the one I want to remove doesn't exist anymore.

Please help me with this before it gets out of hand.

Comment: Ubuntu release?

Answer (score 3):

You can delete all the devices from the website: https://one.ubuntu.com/account/

The easiest way to do this is to start from the Ubuntu One application.

Start it and go to the highlighted link 'Go to the web for public and private sharing options'

[image: U1 web link highlighted]

This opens your default web browser on the Ubuntu One website, you will be logged in already. Click on 'My Account' at the top right.

[image: U1 Website 'my account' link]

Then just scroll down to the Devices section and click on 'Remove Device'

[image: U1 'Remove device' web button]

Comment: This doesn't seem to work properly on Ubuntu 12.04.  It removes the device from the list only, but if you delete the files remaining on the deleted devices Ubuntu One folder, it actually still syncs and deletes the files from the devices which remain in the devices list...